# How to list articles by an author in a views?

Tags: views

In Drupal 7, I have defined a node type 'article' which has an 'author' field (The author is not a user, but just a 3rd party contributor). Now I want to list articles by the each author in a view. How can I do that?

I know that it can be done somehow using contextual filters but got quite perplexed so  appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, i would create a Vocabulary "authors" and add them with a Auto Tag Widget to the Content Type. And add the Authors as a Taxonomy Tag. There are much more Handly then Text Fields.
Then you can easily Create a View with the author Tag. And much more, you can also add more fields to the Taxonomy such as author Picture and Author Description.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the author should be a reference either to an user of the site or to a content type call author, then like you mention using a view you will pass an argument or contextual filter and show only nodes that have that author.

If in you case you don't use a reference, then on your view you just need to add a filter indicating the value of the field with the author name.

Here is where to set the filter:

[image]

Comment: Well the author is just a string as they are entered by admin on the field. So how can make the filter? Thanks

Comment: I added an screenshot indicating where do you go to add a filter to your view.

Comment: oh dear, I know how to add a filter,what should be  at 'Content Type = File'? :)

Comment: Don't worry about that as that only apply to my view. In that case that said that the content type has to be the one call "File" and again that is a content type of my site.

Comment: In you case use Content Type = article